# Posting form data via ajax for esp32 application (small html footprint)

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, forms, post

Writing a simple wifi config for an esp32 application. Trying to have the data submitted back in the request body as json and am trying to use jquery/ajax to accomplish this. Below is my stripped down html page where a user connects to the esp32 application via a soft access point to set the initial wifi. Right now I don't even get the alert('hi') to execute and I'm wondering where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance for any help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function jsonPost(){
              alert('hi');
              $.ajax({
                url: '',
                type: 'POST',
                data:#('my-form').serialize(),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(){alert('Post Complete!');}})}
        </script>
        <style>
            html {
                font-family: Helvetica;
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 0px auto;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Wifi Config</h1>
        <form id="my-form" action="#" onsubmit="jsonPost(); return false;">
          <input type="text" id="ssid" name="ssid" placeholder="ssid" />
          <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your browser console if there any errors .

Comment: No errors, for some reason the post is going out. Inspecting the Network tab show's it's sending it out as a post request but then it's getting received by the server as a get request. I think it may be implementation specific shortcomings on the ESP32 side where it treats everything as a get request.